# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setAllCaps

Tags: android, material-design, android-tabs, android-appcompat

I am using Material Design Sliding Tabs [tutorial](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html), but it supports API 16 and above, but i want to make it compatible with API 10 and above.

**SlidingTabLayout.class:-**

```
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip(); // Line no. - 125
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
 * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    textView.setAllCaps(true); // Line no. 145

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext()); // Line no. - 169
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }

        tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
        tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
    }
}
```

Whenever I use API 10 as minimum, getting :

```
426-426/samples.exoguru.materialtabs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setAllCaps
        at samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout.createDefaultTabView(SlidingTabLayout.java:145)
        at samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout.populateTabStrip(SlidingTabLayout.java:169)
        at samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(SlidingTabLayout.java:125)
        at samples.exoguru.materialtabs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: change to minSdkVersion 7!

Comment: You can use my sliding tabs, if you wish. Compatible with API 7: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/PagerTabStrip.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAllCaps()` was added in API level 14 ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAllCaps(boolean))), so you should not call it w/o checking what version of platfrom you are running on.